# How to get this Browser Plugin for laravel?

Tags: laravel, debugging

Can i Know how do you all get this on your browser inspect.... I am new to laravel and i just saw this in other post...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a browser plugin, its a composer package: `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`

[barryvdh - laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)